# Calculate the Position on rotated node using unProject on plane

Tags: 3d, rotations, plane-geometry, projection

Please HELP

I am not good in maths

Update --> What I am trying to do  is drag the Orthographic camera using mouse pointer around the screen ,
Below calculation is works when Camera is not rotated otherwise it is only works in the one direction

SO I am able to drag the camera  using gestures on the 2D screen

to do this I did following , Which is only work if Camra is not rotated ,

Now Suppose Camera is rotated eular angel 90 degree this calculation not working

How can I add initial rotation in this calculation

Please suggest

```
var previousLocation = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
@objc func panned(gesture:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {


let view = self.sceneView1!
let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)

let location = gesture.location(in: view)
let secLocation = CGPoint(x: location.x + translation.x, y: location.y + translation.y)

let P1 = view.unprojectPoint(SCNVector3(x: Float(location.x), y: Float(location.y), z: 0.0))
let P2 = view.unprojectPoint(SCNVector3(x: Float(location.x), y: Float(location.y), z: 1.0))

   let Q1 = view.unprojectPoint(SCNVector3(x: Float(secLocation.x), y: Float(secLocation.y), z: 0.0))
   let Q2 = view.unprojectPoint(SCNVector3(x: Float(secLocation.x), y: Float(secLocation.y), z: 1.0))

   let t1 = -P1.z / (P2.z - P1.z)
   let t2 = -Q1.z / (Q2.z - Q1.z)

   let x1 = P1.x + t1 * (P2.x - P1.x)
   let y1 = P1.y + t1 * (P2.y - P1.y)

   let P0 = SCNVector3Make(x1, y1,0)

   let x2 = Q1.x + t1 * (Q2.x - Q1.x)
   let y2 = Q1.y + t1 * (Q2.y - Q1.y)

   let Q0 = SCNVector3Make(x2, y2, 0)

   var diffR = Q0 - P0

  diffR = SCNVector3Make(diffR.x * -1, diffR.y * -1, diffR.z * -1)

let cameraNode = view.pointOfView

   switch gesture.state {
   case .began:
       previousLocation = cameraNode!.position
       break;
   case .changed:
    cameraNode?.position = SCNVector3Make(previousLocation.x + diffR.x, previousLocation.y + diffR.y, previousLocation.z + diffR.z)
       break;
   default:
       break;
   }

 }
```

---

Update 2

---

formula I have used is

P1 , P2  ==> ORIGIN  3D VECTOR (X,Y,Z )  AND Q1, Q2  ==> NEW 3D VECTOR (WHERE I NEED TO TRANSLATE)

T1  ,T2 , X1,Y1,PO,Q0  Is calculated as per above

[image]

Comment: Can any one HELP !! PLS

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Ralff I am dragging the Camera (which is 3d obj) in 2d screen with mouse freely ,  With above calculation it is working only  if camera is not rotated with any angles ,  

Like is camera is rotated 90 degree , then I am able to drag only on X axis  not anywhere else

Comment: @Ralff Any help  or suggestion ?

Comment: @Ralff Do you have any idea I am still looking for solution, or anything I can add into question to make it clear

Comment: This question is difficult to answer as I don't know what the functions do e.g., unprojectPoint... My suggestion is try to write out the equation of what the code represents, then I (or others) could advise based on the equations. If equation are provided (in my opinion), people can answer more easily instead of trying to interpret code. If you add equations, tag me in a comment, and I'll look at your question again. Best of luck!